# Run a scraping function on 2 threads for 2 URLs Python

Tags: python, multithreading, beautifulsoup, python-multithreading

I have the following scraping function already implemented in serial, but, because There are multiple URLs with data I would like to parallelize some of the work. here is the working Serial code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests

edbURL='URL1'
psnURL='URL2'

def urlScraper(URL):
    page=requests.get(URL)
    soup=bs(page.text,'lxml')
    l = ['base_URL'+str(i.a['href']) for i in soup.find_all('div',class_='info')]
    return l

edbs=urlScraper(edbURL)
psns=urlScraper(psnURL)
```

What I would like for the two calls to `urlScraper(URL)` to each get their own thread and run in parallel, I tried using the `threads` library but only got some big nasty `int` returns with the following syntax:

```
edbs = threads.start_new_thread(urlScraper,(edbURL,))
psns = threads.start_new_thread(urlScraper,(psnURL,))
```

I figure it has something to do with the `return` in `urlScraper(URL)`, then again, I basically know almost nothing about anything. Thanks for any help everyone!

Comment: If you are hoping that they will actually work in parallel and will therefore be fast then it doesn't happen in python. Threads dont actually run in parallel. See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1697571/python-threading-appears-to-run-threads-sequentially

Comment: I suppose if I actually wanted them in parallel I could use cython and openmp?

Comment: You can use multiprocessing to run them in parallel.

Comment: How does the performance of multiprocessing compare to that of cython/openmp? It seems like it must use subprocess or some other library which to me means extra overhead, then again, it also means less manual memory management.

Answer (score -2):

multiprocessing is a package that supports spawning processes using an API similar to the threading module. The multiprocessing package offers both local and remote concurrency, effectively side-stepping the Global Interpreter Lock by using subprocesses instead of threads. Due to this, the multiprocessing module allows the programmer to fully leverage multiple processors on a given machine. It runs on both Unix and Windows.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html