# Python 3 run two applcations in windows parallel

Tags: multithreading, python-3.x, subprocess

one question: I want to run two different exe files parallel (Windows).
All my tests starts the two applications, but one after the other (after closing the application). What's wrong?

```
import threading
import subprocess
import os.path

def Worker(aPrg):
    _, name = os.path.split(aPrg)
    if os.path.isfile(aPrg):
        lExe = []
        lExe.append(aPrg)
        print('Start: ' + name)
        lResult = subprocess.call(lExe)
    else:
        print('ERROR: ' + name + ' not available!')
    return

def main():
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=Worker('C:\\windows\\notepad.exe'))
    t2 = threading.Thread(target=Worker('c:\\windows\\explorer.exe'))
    t1.start()
    t2.start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

Thanks for all ideas!

Geosucher

Answer (score 0):

The reasons for this problem is discussed here : [Python threading appears to run threads sequentially](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1697571/python-threading-appears-to-run-threads-sequentially)

This should help you:

```
import subprocess
import os.path
import multiprocessing

def Worker(aPrg):
    _, name = os.path.split(aPrg)
    if os.path.isfile(aPrg):
        lExe = []
        lExe.append(aPrg)
        print('Start: ' + name)
        lResult = subprocess.call(lExe)
    else:
        print('ERROR: ' + name + ' not available!')
    return

def main():
    p = multiprocessing.Pool(2)
    p.map(Worker, ('c:\\windows\\explorer.exe','c:\\windows\\explorer.exe'))

if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

Comment: Thank you! it works fine. I observed that another posiibility is to use Popen instead of call.